# Creating shortcut for Firefox add-on options

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I want to *easily* switch how Firefox works, using an Add-on feature either toggled on or off, based on which one of us is using a particular computer. Currently, to toggle that, we are having to do this tedious sequence each time:

1. Tools
2. Add-ons*
3. Options (of the add-on I need)
4. Uncheck checkbox to toggle the thing I wanted to toggle.
5. Click OK
6. Close the tab that was opened

(*And yes, I know I can get to 3 by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or putting a favorite in the favorites bar to the Add-ons Manager screen...but even steps 3-6 are still tedious enough.)

Instead, what I'd love to have is either (best) an icon in the menu bar that can indicate the toggle state of that option--a helpful reminder--and that you can click on to toggle it, OR a simple shortcut key sequence I can assign, or both.

Is it reasonably possible to do that?

Comment: Why are you not using different profiles? This is exactly what profiles are for ....

Comment: @DavidPostill I looked into profiles briefly online; seems like they don't actually store Add-ons, let alone add-ons' states. Have I got that wrong, and is there a quick shortcut to switch profiles?

Comment: On my machine at least Extension information is stored in my profile `C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\5ubcfk8m.default\extensions`

Comment: [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)" "The Profile Manager allows you to create, remove, rename, and switch profiles."

Comment: [Profile folder - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox): "Firefox stores a **user's personal information** such as bookmarks, **extensions**, and user preferences in a unique profile. "